# How to call action only on Action column image not on grid cell

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs-grid

In grid 'actioncolumn' i displayed an image using 'renderer' like,

image + text

On action column click i am calling some action,

but click event is triggering even click on empty space in grid cell.
how to prevent that click on empty space.

how to identify click on link (image+text), not on grid cell empty space.

```
{
          xtype: 'actioncolumn',
          width: '17%',      
          text: 'Display Option',
          renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
          var label = '';
            if (record.get('status') == 0) {
                     lable = 'Show';
                     etadata.style += 'margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer;';
                     return '<span style="font-size: 14px; color:#3b87de; font-family:arial; margin-left:-3px;">' + '<img src="resources/images/show_msg.png"/>' + label + '</span>'
              } else {
                metadata.style += 'margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer;';
                 lable = 'Hide';
                   return '<span style="font-size: 14px; color:#3b87de; font-family:arial;">' + '<img src="resources/images/hide_fault.png"/>' + label + '</span>'
                            }                              

                                },
                                handler:function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e){
console.log('handler test');//not triggering
                                },
                                listeners: {

                                    click: function ( grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
console.log('handler test');// triggering
                    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you link the action to the actioncolumn? I frequently use actioncolumns and never had this issue. I will paste the code I usually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.2, and I never had the issue. I define my actioncolumns like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        tooltip: Lang._('Tooltip for edit'),
        handler: function(grid, ri, ci, me, e, rec, rEl) {this.up('grid').fireEvent('editAction', grid, ri, ci, me, e, rec, rEl)},
        getClass: function(value, metadata, record){
            return '[css class for background image]'
        }
    },{
        ...
    }],
    menuDisabled: true
}
```

The in the controller I have:

```
init: function(){
    this.control({
        '[xtype of grid]': {
            editAction: this.onEditAction,
        }
    })
},
onEditAction: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, me, event, record, rowEl){
    Ext.Msg.alert('Info', 'edit clicked')
},
```

Probably you defined the handler for the action column, instead of definig a handler for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the event parameter passed into the handler, see the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-handler

With the event object you can look at the target and see if its an element you want to process, if it's not you can just return false to prevent anything else happening.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply, i tried but not working, 'click' event only triggering. but this event working on both image+text and empty space in cell.

Comment: OK handler is actually used if you have configured the icon property which in your case you are not. So if the click listener is working, you should be able to get to the event itself in that function, event is normally passed as the last param on a click listener

Comment: Yes, I am getting event as last param, and target is span when click on link and  target is div.x-grid-cell-inner when i click on empty space in cell. I am observed while debugging. how to get it in click listener.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: I did it like this                                                                  if(el.dom.tagName=='SPAN' || el.dom.tagName=='IMG' ){  //action }                      Thank you @mindparse

Answer (score 0):

You can override the "Ext.grid.column.Action" class with an overrriden method defaultRenderer.

Inside the items config of the actioncolumn - provide some custom configs like 
img: 'image path'
text: 'your text'

and check for the existense of these configs inside the defaultRenderer method and thus return

```
 '<span style="font-size: 14px; color:#3b87de; font-family:arial;">' + '<img src="resources/images/hide_fault.png"/>' + label + '</span>'
```

or

```
'<span style="font-size: 14px; color:#3b87de; font-family:arial; margin-left:-3px;">' + '<img src="resources/images/show_msg.png"/>' + label + '</span>'
```

This way the handler that you define for that item will be invoked only when the image is clicked.

You might have to take  care of some css..